# how do I increase the font size of the labels in my box plots?

Tags: r, ggplot2, label

I am trying to visualize the performance of students with different backgrounds for three university programmes. I'm doing this with a number of box plots for each programme (measuring percentage of academic credits taken), sorted by the median academic credits for each backgrund.

The plot for each programme is coded as follows:

```
boxplots_gymnasiegrov_reg_ekon <- fulldata%>%filter(urvalsgrupp!="omregistrerad" & antalreg<=1)%>%
filter(totstatus_tri!="tidigt avbrott eller återbud" & program=="Ekonom")%>%
ggplot(aes(x=fct_reorder(gymnasiegrov, PERC_CREDIT, .fun = median,na.rm=T), y = PERC_CREDIT)) +
geom_boxplot() + coord_flip()

boxplots_gymnasiegrov_reg_mekon <- fulldata%>%filter(urvalsgrupp!="omregistrerad" & antalreg<=1)%>%
filter(totstatus_tri!="tidigt avbrott eller återbud" & program=="Maklarekonom")%>%
ggplot(aes(x=fct_reorder(gymnasiegrov, PERC_CREDIT, .fun = median,na.rm=T), y = PERC_CREDIT)) + geom_boxplot() + coord_flip()

boxplots_gymnasiegrov_reg_digi <- fulldata%>%filter(urvalsgrupp!="omregistrerad" & antalreg<=1)%>%
filter(totstatus_tri!="tidigt avbrott eller återbud" & program=="Digitala_Medier")%>%
ggplot(aes(x=fct_reorder(gymnasiegrov, PERC_CREDIT, .fun = median,na.rm=T), y = PERC_CREDIT)) + geom_boxplot() + coord_flip()
```

When I visualize the programmes simultaneously I want to use ggarrange, since I want all programmes to be ordered by best to worst background, and since this order will differ across programmes.

I try the following:

```
ggarrange(boxplots_gymnasiegrov_reg_ekon, boxplots_gymnasiegrov_reg_mekon, boxplots_gymnasiegrov_reg_digi, ncol=3)+
  theme(axis.text=element_text(size=18))
```

However, when I do this the labels on the x axis (the vertical axis since the axes are flipped) becomes too small to read:

[image]

It doesn't seem to matter what I do.

So far I have tried:

```
-To increase the text via HTML tags
-Using the font.size argument in ggarrange
-Increasing the height and width of the plot in Rmarkdown
-Using the font argument in gglot2
-Using the theme argument in gglot2
```

How can I solve this and make my labels readable?

Small excerpt of data:

```
structure(list(start_date = structure(c(18140, 18140, 18140, 
18140, 17041, 17041, 17041, 18140, 15585, 15585, 15585, 15585, 
15585, 15949, 15949, 15949, 16313, 16313, 16313, 16313, 16313, 
16677, 16677, 16677, 16677, 17041, 17041, 17041, 17405, 17776, 
17776, 17776, 17776, 15585, 17776, 17776, 17776, 15585, 15585, 
15585, 15585, 15585, 15585, 15585, 15585, 15585, 15585, 15585, 
15585, 15585), class = "Date"), PERC_CREDIT = c(0, 76.6666666666667, 
70, 100, 0, 0, 91.6666666666667, 5, 50, 0, 79.1666666666667, 
83.8888888888889, 70.8333333333333, 63.0555555555556, 95.8333333333333, 
44.4444444444444, 50, 33.3333333333333, 51.6666666666667, 100, 
92.7777777777778, 91.6666666666667, 100, 17.2222222222222, 33.3333333333333, 
37.5, 41.6666666666667, 38.0555555555556, 55.5555555555556, 60, 
40, 40, 80, 66.6666666666667, 0, 6, 20, 100, 91.6666666666667, 
0, 100, 0, 91.6666666666667, 89.1666666666667, 100, 12.5, 100, 
83.3333333333333, 100, 87.5), gymnasiegrov = structure(c(2L, 
5L, 12L, 9L, 1L, 3L, 17L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 9L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 
6L, 9L, 6L), .Label = c("komvux", "Handels- och administrationsprogrammet", 
"Oklart", "bygg, el, fordon, hantverk, sjöfart, industriteknik", 
"friskoleprogram", "specialutformat program", "Vård- och Omsorgsprogrammet", 
"medieprogrammet", "samhälls- och ekonomiprogrammet", "naturvetenskapliga programmet", 
"samhällsvetenskapliga programmet", "teknikprogrammet", "ekonomiprogrammet/ juridik", 
"ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "estetiska programmet", "naturbruksprogrammet", 
"Barn- och Fritidsprogrammet", "Hotell- och Restaurang"), class = c("ordered", 
"factor")), urvalsgrupp = c("'Sen Anmälan'", "'Sen Anmälan'", 
"'Sen Anmälan'", "'Sen Anmälan'", "'Sen Anmälan'", "'Sen Anmälan'", 
"'Sen Anmälan'", "'Sen Anmälan'", "Antagen senare del", "Antagen senare del", 
"Antagen senare del", "Antagen senare del", "Antagen senare del", 
"Antagen senare del", "Antagen senare del", "Antagen senare del", 
"Antagen senare del", "Antagen senare del", "Antagen senare del", 
"Antagen senare del", "Antagen senare del", "Antagen senare del", 
"Antagen senare del", "Antagen senare del", "Antagen senare del", 
"Antagen senare del", "Antagen senare del", "Antagen senare del", 
"Antagen senare del", "Antagen senare del", "Antagen senare del", 
"Antagen senare del", "Antagen senare del", "Antagen senare del", 
"Antagen senare del", "Antagen senare del", "Antagen senare del", 
"betyg", "betyg", "betyg", "betyg", "betyg", "betyg", "betyg", 
"betyg", "betyg", "betyg", "betyg", "betyg", "betyg"), program = c("Ekonom", 
"Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Maklarekonom", "Digitala_Medier", "Digitala_Medier", 
"Digitala_Medier", "Digitala_Medier", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", 
"Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", 
"Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", 
"Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", 
"Ekonom", "Maklarekonom", "Maklarekonom", "Maklarekonom", "Maklarekonom", 
"Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", 
"Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom"), 
    totstatus_tri = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
    3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("pågående studier", 
    "tidigt avbrott eller återbud", "sent avbrott"), class = c("ordered", 
    "factor")), antalreg = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-50L), groups = structure(list(start_date = structure(c(15585, 
15949, 16313, 16677, 17041, 17405, 17776, 18140), class = "Date"), 
    .rows = list(c(9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 34L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 
    41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L), 14:16, 
        17:21, 22:25, c(5L, 6L, 7L, 26L, 27L, 28L), 29L, c(30L, 
        31L, 32L, 33L, 35L, 36L, 37L), c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 8L))), row.names = c(NA, 
-8L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Large subset of data:

```
structure(list(start_date = structure(c(18140, 18140, 18140, 
18140, 17041, 17041, 17041, 18140, 15585, 15585, 15585, 15585, 
15585, 15949, 15949, 15949, 16313, 16313, 16313, 16313, 16313, 
16677, 16677, 16677, 16677, 17041, 17041, 17041, 17405, 17776, 
17776, 17776, 17776, 15585, 17776, 17776, 17776, 15585, 15585, 
15585, 15585, 15585, 15585, 15585, 15585, 15585, 15585, 15585, 
15585, 15585, 15585, 15585, 15585, 15585, 15585, 15585, 15585, 
15585, 15585, 15585, 15585, 15585, 15585, 15585, 15585, 15585, 
15585, 15585, 15585, 15585, 15585, 15585, 15585, 15585, 15585, 
15585, 15585, 15585, 15585, 15585, 15585, 15585, 15585, 15585, 
15585, 15949, 15949, 15949, 15949, 15949, 15949, 15949, 15949, 
15949, 15949, 15949, 15949, 15949, 15949, 15949, 15949, 15949, 
15949, 15949, 15949, 15949, 15949, 15949, 15949, 15949, 15949, 
15949, 15949, 15949, 15949, 15949, 15949, 15949, 15949, 15949, 
15949, 15949, 15949, 15949, 15949, 15949, 15949, 15949, 15949, 
15949, 15949, 15949, 15949, 15949, 15949, 15949, 15949, 15949, 
15949, 15949, 16313, 16313, 16313, 16313, 16313, 16313, 16313, 
16313, 16313, 16313, 16313, 16313, 16313, 16313, 16313, 16313, 
16313, 16313, 16313, 16313, 16313, 16313, 16313, 16313, 16313, 
16313, 16313, 16313, 16313, 16313, 16313, 16313, 16313, 16313, 
16313, 16313, 16313, 16313, 16313, 16313, 16313, 16313, 16313, 
16313, 16313, 16677, 16677, 16677, 16677, 16677, 16677, 16677, 
16677, 16677, 16677, 16677, 16677, 16677, 16677, 16677), class = "Date"), 
    PERC_CREDIT = c(0, 76.6666666666667, 70, 100, 0, 0, 91.6666666666667, 
    5, 50, 0, 79.1666666666667, 83.8888888888889, 70.8333333333333, 
    63.0555555555556, 95.8333333333333, 44.4444444444444, 50, 
    33.3333333333333, 51.6666666666667, 100, 92.7777777777778, 
    91.6666666666667, 100, 17.2222222222222, 33.3333333333333, 
    37.5, 41.6666666666667, 38.0555555555556, 55.5555555555556, 
    60, 40, 40, 80, 66.6666666666667, 0, 6, 20, 100, 91.6666666666667, 
    0, 100, 0, 91.6666666666667, 89.1666666666667, 100, 12.5, 
    100, 83.3333333333333, 100, 87.5, 33.3333333333333, 9.44444444444444, 
    100, 4.16666666666667, 0, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 91.6666666666667, 
    91.6666666666667, 2.22222222222222, 95.8333333333333, 71.9444444444444, 
    100, 100, 17.2222222222222, 100, 83.8888888888889, 96.3888888888889, 
    62.5, 100, 100, 100, 16.6666666666667, 95.8333333333333, 
    0, 92.2222222222222, 91.6666666666667, 68.3333333333333, 
    91.6666666666667, 2.22222222222222, 0, 100, 0, 0, 87.5, 0, 
    0, 95.8333333333333, 100, 83.8888888888889, 60, 0, 100, 100, 
    91.6666666666667, 100, 95.8333333333333, 100, 13.0555555555556, 
    0, 95.8333333333333, 100, 100, 83.3333333333333, 0, 95.8333333333333, 
    13.0555555555556, 100, 100, 9.44444444444444, 83.3333333333333, 
    100, 88.6111111111111, 1.11111111111111, 95.8333333333333, 
    0, 25, 100, 100, 0, 0, 95.8333333333333, 100, 100, 0, 2.22222222222222, 
    87.5, 88.0555555555556, 13.0555555555556, 100, 0, 14.1666666666667, 
    0, 0, 100, 25, 100, 100, 33.3333333333333, 46.9444444444444, 
    0, 83.8888888888889, 91.6666666666667, 70, 0, 0, 3.05555555555556, 
    91.6666666666667, 95.8333333333333, 29.1666666666667, 95.8333333333333, 
    0, 0, 100, 96.6666666666667, 93.3333333333333, 66.6666666666667, 
    100, 0, 0, 64.1666666666667, 95.8333333333333, 0, 20.8333333333333, 
    91.6666666666667, 100, 14.1666666666667, 100, 100, 92.7777777777778, 
    100, 83.3333333333333, 10.5555555555556, 100, 100, 100, 100, 
    100, 91.6666666666667, 0, 31.3888888888889, 0, 0, 0, 95.8333333333333, 
    9.44444444444444, 0, 100, 43.3333333333333, 66.6666666666667, 
    0, 83.3333333333333, 0, 9.44444444444444, 0, 83.3333333333333, 
    100), gymnasiegrov = structure(c(2L, 5L, 12L, 9L, 1L, 3L, 
    17L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 9L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 9L, 
    6L, 15L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 12L, 9L, 5L, 9L, 3L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 
    3L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 9L, 9L, 2L, 5L, 11L, 9L, 16L, 9L, 5L, 9L, 
    11L, 11L, 5L, 9L, 2L, 5L, 9L, 5L, 6L, 10L, 12L, 9L, 11L, 
    9L, 6L, 15L, 5L, 6L, 9L, 5L, 9L, 2L, 9L, 5L, 11L, 9L, 5L, 
    5L, 9L, 9L, 11L, 5L, 5L, 10L, 10L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 9L, 5L, 9L, 
    2L, 5L, 10L, 9L, 11L, 5L, 5L, 9L, 11L, 9L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
    6L, 9L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 9L, 9L, 3L, 6L, 18L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 
    5L, 9L, 10L, 3L, 2L, 6L, 9L, 11L, 9L, 9L, 2L, 9L, 9L, 5L, 
    9L, 9L, 11L, 5L, 9L, 5L, 9L, 6L, 9L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 13L, 
    14L, 14L, 14L, 11L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 11L, 14L, 14L, 13L, 14L, 
    9L, 5L, 10L, 9L, 6L, 5L, 11L, 5L, 9L, 6L, 9L, 6L, 11L, 6L, 
    11L), .Label = c("komvux", "Handels- och administrationsprogrammet", 
    "Oklart", "bygg, el, fordon, hantverk, sjöfart, industriteknik", 
    "friskoleprogram", "specialutformat program", "Vård- och Omsorgsprogrammet", 
    "medieprogrammet", "samhälls- och ekonomiprogrammet", "naturvetenskapliga programmet", 
    "samhällsvetenskapliga programmet", "teknikprogrammet", "ekonomiprogrammet/ juridik", 
    "ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "estetiska programmet", "naturbruksprogrammet", 
    "Barn- och Fritidsprogrammet", "Hotell- och Restaurang"), class = c("ordered", 
    "factor")), urvalsgrupp = c("'Sen Anmälan'", "'Sen Anmälan'", 
    "'Sen Anmälan'", "'Sen Anmälan'", "'Sen Anmälan'", "'Sen Anmälan'", 
    "'Sen Anmälan'", "'Sen Anmälan'", "Antagen senare del", "Antagen senare del", 
    "Antagen senare del", "Antagen senare del", "Antagen senare del", 
    "Antagen senare del", "Antagen senare del", "Antagen senare del", 
    "Antagen senare del", "Antagen senare del", "Antagen senare del", 
    "Antagen senare del", "Antagen senare del", "Antagen senare del", 
    "Antagen senare del", "Antagen senare del", "Antagen senare del", 
    "Antagen senare del", "Antagen senare del", "Antagen senare del", 
    "Antagen senare del", "Antagen senare del", "Antagen senare del", 
    "Antagen senare del", "Antagen senare del", "Antagen senare del", 
    "Antagen senare del", "Antagen senare del", "Antagen senare del", 
    "betyg", "betyg", "betyg", "betyg", "betyg", "betyg", "betyg", 
    "betyg", "betyg", "betyg", "betyg", "betyg", "betyg", "betyg", 
    "betyg", "betyg", "betyg", "betyg", "betyg", "betyg", "betyg", 
    "betyg", "betyg", "betyg", "betyg", "betyg", "betyg", "betyg", 
    "betyg", "betyg", "betyg", "betyg", "betyg", "betyg", "betyg", 
    "betyg", "betyg", "betyg", "betyg", "betyg", "betyg", "betyg", 
    "betyg", "betyg", "betyg", "betyg", "betyg", "betyg", "betyg", 
    "betyg", "betyg", "betyg", "betyg", "betyg", "betyg", "betyg", 
    "betyg", "betyg", "betyg", "betyg", "betyg", "betyg", "betyg", 
    "betyg", "betyg", "betyg", "betyg", "betyg", "betyg", "betyg", 
    "betyg", "betyg", "betyg", "betyg", "betyg", "betyg", "betyg", 
    "betyg", "betyg", "betyg", "betyg", "betyg", "betyg", "betyg", 
    "betyg", "betyg", "betyg", "betyg", "betyg", "betyg", "betyg", 
    "betyg", "betyg", "betyg", "betyg", "betyg", "betyg", "betyg", 
    "betyg", "betyg", "betyg", "betyg", "betyg", "betyg", "betyg", 
    "betyg", "betyg", "betyg", "betyg", "betyg", "betyg", "betyg", 
    "betyg", "betyg", "betyg", "betyg", "betyg", "betyg", "betyg", 
    "betyg", "betyg", "betyg", "betyg", "betyg", "betyg", "betyg", 
    "betyg", "betyg", "betyg", "betyg", "betyg", "betyg", "betyg", 
    "betyg", "betyg", "betyg", "betyg", "betyg", "betyg", "betyg", 
    "betyg", "betyg", "betyg", "betyg", "betyg", "betyg", "betyg", 
    "betyg", "betyg", "betyg", "betyg", "betyg", "betyg", "betyg", 
    "betyg", "betyg", "betyg", "betyg", "betyg", "betyg", "betyg", 
    "betyg", "betyg"), program = c("Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", 
    "Maklarekonom", "Digitala_Medier", "Digitala_Medier", "Digitala_Medier", 
    "Digitala_Medier", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", 
    "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", 
    "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", 
    "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", 
    "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Maklarekonom", "Maklarekonom", 
    "Maklarekonom", "Maklarekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", 
    "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", 
    "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", 
    "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", 
    "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", 
    "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", 
    "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", 
    "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", 
    "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", 
    "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", 
    "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", 
    "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", 
    "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", 
    "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", 
    "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", 
    "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", 
    "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", 
    "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", 
    "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", 
    "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", 
    "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", 
    "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", 
    "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", 
    "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", 
    "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", 
    "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", 
    "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", 
    "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom"), totstatus_tri = structure(c(2L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
    3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
    1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
    3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 
    3L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("pågående studier", "tidigt avbrott eller återbud", 
    "sent avbrott"), class = c("ordered", "factor")), antalreg = c(1L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 2L)), row.names = c(NA, -200L), groups = structure(list(
    start_date = structure(c(15585, 15949, 16313, 16677, 17041, 
    17405, 17776, 18140), class = "Date"), .rows = list(c(9L, 
    10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 34L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 
    45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 56L, 
    57L, 58L, 59L, 60L, 61L, 62L, 63L, 64L, 65L, 66L, 67L, 68L, 
    69L, 70L, 71L, 72L, 73L, 74L, 75L, 76L, 77L, 78L, 79L, 80L, 
    81L, 82L, 83L, 84L, 85L), c(14L, 15L, 16L, 86L, 87L, 88L, 
    89L, 90L, 91L, 92L, 93L, 94L, 95L, 96L, 97L, 98L, 99L, 100L, 
    101L, 102L, 103L, 104L, 105L, 106L, 107L, 108L, 109L, 110L, 
    111L, 112L, 113L, 114L, 115L, 116L, 117L, 118L, 119L, 120L, 
    121L, 122L, 123L, 124L, 125L, 126L, 127L, 128L, 129L, 130L, 
    131L, 132L, 133L, 134L, 135L, 136L, 137L, 138L, 139L, 140L
    ), c(17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 141L, 142L, 143L, 144L, 145L, 
    146L, 147L, 148L, 149L, 150L, 151L, 152L, 153L, 154L, 155L, 
    156L, 157L, 158L, 159L, 160L, 161L, 162L, 163L, 164L, 165L, 
    166L, 167L, 168L, 169L, 170L, 171L, 172L, 173L, 174L, 175L, 
    176L, 177L, 178L, 179L, 180L, 181L, 182L, 183L, 184L, 185L
    ), c(22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 186L, 187L, 188L, 189L, 190L, 191L, 
    192L, 193L, 194L, 195L, 196L, 197L, 198L, 199L, 200L), c(5L, 
    6L, 7L, 26L, 27L, 28L), 29L, c(30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 35L, 36L, 
    37L), c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 8L))), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, ggarrange doesn't like being told what to do by mere ggplot commands. If I increase the font size inside each separate plot I can pass that on to the ggarrange function.

Also, the flup in coord_flip isn't just cosmetic, which means we'll have to change the plot for the y axis and not hte x axis.

```
boxplots_gymnasiegrov_reg_ekon <- fulldata%>%filter(urvalsgrupp!="omregistrerad" & antalreg<=1)%>%
filter(totstatus_tri!="tidigt avbrott eller återbud" & program=="Ekonom")%>%
ggplot(aes(x=fct_reorder(gymnasiegrov, PERC_CREDIT, .fun = median,na.rm=T), y = PERC_CREDIT)) +
geom_boxplot() + coord_flip()+theme(axis.text.y=element_text(size=18))

boxplots_gymnasiegrov_reg_mekon <- fulldata%>%filter(urvalsgrupp!="omregistrerad" & antalreg<=1)%>%
filter(totstatus_tri!="tidigt avbrott eller återbud" & program=="Maklarekonom")%>%
ggplot(aes(x=fct_reorder(gymnasiegrov, PERC_CREDIT, .fun = median,na.rm=T), y = PERC_CREDIT)) +
geom_boxplot() + coord_flip()+theme(axis.text.y=element_text(size=18))

boxplots_gymnasiegrov_reg_digi <- fulldata%>%filter(urvalsgrupp!="omregistrerad" & antalreg<=1)%>%
filter(totstatus_tri!="tidigt avbrott eller återbud" & program=="Digitala_Medier")%>%
ggplot(aes(x=fct_reorder(gymnasiegrov, PERC_CREDIT, .fun = median,na.rm=T), y = PERC_CREDIT)) +
geom_boxplot() + coord_flip()+theme(axis.text.y=element_text(size=18))
```